# jQuery UI datepicker: Can you format a date and allow multiple seperator characters?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I prefer my datepicker to be formatted with this option

```
{dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'}
```

Ex: 06-16-2010

But, I would like to allow people to enter in a slash as a seperator instead of a dash if they choose.

Is there a way to setup the datepicker so that it defaults to mm-dd-yy but wouldn't prevent someone from entering mm/dd/yy?

I do know I can set {constrainInput:false} although then people can enter letters :(

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the datepicker has the altField & altFormat option so you can show one format but send the other, but thats not what you want.

i suggest that you use datejs (http://www.datejs.com/) to parse the user input and update a hidden textbox which is linked to your datepicker.

Answer (score 22):

Absolutely.  You can type anything into the field if you turn off constrainInput.

```
$( "#myDateInput" ).datepicker({ 
  dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
  constrainInput: false
});
```

Full docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-constrainInput

Comment: Thanks for the contrainInput

Answer (score 0):

The constraininput will do the trick.  I was trying to do a similar thing, and I bound the change to do a few extra things.  You can use any delimiter.  / - . , space etc.  It converts any non digit to /.  If you enter m/d or m/d/ it will add the current year using any delimiter.  If you do T or t, it will return the current day.  You can do T10 or T+10 and it will return today plus 10 days.  You can do t-10 and it will return 10 days prior.  You can change the 2 places where it has "mm-dd-y" to use your desired format.  This solution should work for international format as except for the auto date add, but I did not test it for that.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#STARTDATE" ).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: 4,
      showButtonPanel: true,
      constrainInput: false,
   dateFormat: "mm-dd-y"
    });
 $( "#STARTDATE" ).change(function() {
   if ($("#STARTDATE").val().toUpperCase().indexOf("T") >= 0) {
       Days = parseInt("0" + $("#STARTDATE").val().replace(/\D/g,''));
       if ($("#STARTDATE").val().indexOf('-') >= 0){Days*=-1}
       var tdate = new Date();
       tdate.setDate(tdate.getDate() + Days);
   } else {
       var tdate = $("#STARTDATE").val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '/');
    var tvar = tdate.split("/");
    if (tvar.length == 3){
     if (tvar[2] == "") {tdate += new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)}
    }
    if (tvar.length == 2){tdate += "/" + new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(-2)}
       try {
      tdate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/y', tdate);
    } catch (Error) {
        try {
       tdate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', tdate);
       } catch (Error) {
        }
       }
   }
   tdate = $.datepicker.formatDate( "mm-dd-y", new Date( tdate ) );
   $( "#STARTDATE" ).val(tdate);
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Also, need to swap STARTDATE with your date field ID.